# Pivot Column of varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m trying to PIVOT some data in a table, but I cannot do it because I do not find the way to do it using varchar columns. I have this table:

```
declare @table  table(name VARCHAR(50) not null, occupation VARCHAR(MAX))

insert into @table values ('A','Doctor')
insert into @table values ('B','Doctor')
insert into @table values ('A','Professor')
insert into @table values ('A','Singer')
insert into @table values ('A','Actor')

SELECT 

CASE WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN NAME END AS Doctor,
CASE WHEN occupation = 'Professor' THEN NAME END AS Professor,
CASE WHEN occupation = 'Singer' THEN NAME END AS Singer,
CASE WHEN occupation = 'Actor' THEN NAME END AS Actor
FROM @table
```

Output:

```
Doctor  Professor   Singer  Actor
A   NULL    NULL    NULL
B   NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    A   NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    A   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    A
```

And for Pivot i get this output:

```
select * from 
(
select name, occupation from @table ) src
pivot (
min(name)
for occupation in ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])) as pvt

Doctor  Professor   Singer  Actor
A        A          A       A
```

And for min / max / function the pivot function gives me only partial output, for the count function I get number of records for doctor, singer etc.. But I need actual rows, not the row count.

What I need is this:

```
Doctor  Professor   Singer  Actor
A        A          A       A   
B       NULL        NULL    NULL
```

i.e suppose if we have 5 name for doctors we need to show 5 entries for doctor column.

Answer (score 2):

I find this easier to express as conditional aggregation using a sequential number generated using `row_number():

```
select max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) as Doctor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) as Professor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) as Singer,
       max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) as Actor     
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) as seqnum
      from @table t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks! :).
But Order by is not ordering in ascending order for other records, Actually i need to order all the columns in ascending  , So i gave order by 1,2,3,4

Comment: @max . . . If you want the names in ascending order, then use `order by name` in the `order by` clause for `row_number()`.

Comment: i felt that we can do that with row_number(), And In fact i have written the sub-query separately also. But i was not knowing to merge both the case statement of outer and actual column with rowid of inner query.

Comment: Sorry i trying to order by on the outside query

Comment: Hi Can anyone please explain me what GROUP BY will do actually in the outer query. And this is my understanding .
The inner will give me the actual columns from the base table, with sequence number field  Example for Doctor we have two records so we get 1,2 as sequence number and Outer query gives me the denormalized columns. and yes i know GROUP BY will group the result set i.e we eliminate duplicate records Example, if we have A DOCTOR 2 entries only one will be shown.

Comment: @max . . . You seem to understand what the `group by` does.  The inner query calculates the position in the "column list" for each name.  The outer query then creates these lists based on the position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` as you proposed, just add column with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT [Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor]
FROM (SELECT name, occupation,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY occupation) 
      FROM @table ) AS src
PIVOT (
  MIN(name)
  FOR occupation IN ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])
) AS pvt
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411953)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Doctor ║ Professor ║ Singer ║ Actor ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ A      ║ A         ║ A      ║ A     ║
║ B      ║           ║        ║       ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

**EDIT:**

You did not write how to handle more rows so consider this case.
Above solution will return:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Doctor ║ Professor ║ Singer ║ Actor ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ A      ║ A         ║ A      ║ A     ║
║ B      ║           ║ C      ║       ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

vs:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Doctor ║ Professor ║ Singer ║ Actor ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ A      ║ A         ║ A      ║ A     ║
║ B      ║           ║        ║       ║
║        ║           ║ C      ║       ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

If you want second case use:

```
SELECT [Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor]
FROM (SELECT name, occupation,
             rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) 
      FROM @table ) AS src
PIVOT (
  MIN(name)
  FOR occupation IN ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])
) AS pvt
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411977)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi @lad2025, Nice post. Actually i need all the columns to be ordered in ascending

Comment: thanks @lad2025 Sorry i trying to order by on the outside query